# Uploading multiple images of faces (5-10 face images, same dimensions), change to matrix and perform PCA from scratch in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, pca

kindly help. I'm new to programming and i'm a bit confused.

I need to take an upload of 5 -10 pictures and perform PCA from scratch on them. but my plot output for the second tab is not rendering for the **prop table** . ** ALL Images display well on the first tab**, the issue comes on the processes after. ill appreciate some clarity on how to use Rshiny, i feel like I'm missing something that's fundamental.

```
library(shiny)
library(EBImage)

#ui

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Eigenfaces"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel (
            fileInput("images","Upload images", multiple = T, accept = c('image/png',"image/jpeg"))
        ),
        
        mainPanel(  
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel('Images for PCA', plotOutput("image")),
                tabPanel('Matrix', plotOutput("matrix"))
            )
        )
        
        
        
    ))

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    img <- reactive ({
        f<- input$images
        if(is.null(f))
            return(NULL)
      readImage(f$datapath)
       
        
    })
    
    
    output$image <- renderPlot({
        req(img())
        plot(img(), all = TRUE)
        
    })
    
    
    output$matrix <- renderPlot({
        
        req(img())
        image_matrix <-do.call('cbind',lapply(img(),as.numeric))
        #covaraince matrix
        im <-scale(image_matrix, center = TRUE)
        images <- cov(im)
        #eigen computation
        eigen_comp<-eigen(images)
        #eigen vectors
        eigen_vec <-eigen_comp$vectors
        #eigen values        
        eigen_values <-eigen_comp$values
        #proportion of eigen values
        y = round(prop.table(eigen_values),3)
        plot(y, type ="b")
       
        
       
    })
    
}    


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you checked the functions in the `renderPlot` for the `output$matrix` outside of shiny? I've tried it with a very small picture and it already stops because it needs way too much RAM

Comment: yes i was able to resolve this last night, i just needed to bring the images in as a list before further processing. Thank you!

Comment: Then please add your solution as the answer and accept it, so when someone has the problem later they can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the as.list function i was able to bring the images in and get the plots

```
matrices <- reactive ({
     req(img)
        if(is.null(img()))
            return(NULL)
        f<- input$images
        faces <- as.list(f$datapath)
        image_list= lapply(faces,readImage)
        image_matrix <-do.call('cbind',lapply(image_list,as.numeric))
        y <-scale(image_matrix, center= TRUE)   
    })
```

[faces for PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtmTc.png)

[Variance plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFPk.png)